# Is there a comment button for the history stack-exchange?

Tags: support, comments

Hi I'm an avid member of the stack-exchange sites.

As a history major I love the idea of a history Q&A site and the formatting, style and overall design of the Stack-exchange sites presents a friendly interface and a beautiful layout.

But as a member of Stack-Overflow and other sites I don't seem to have a "comment" button on the History Stack-exchange. I can't tell if this is an individual or localized bug or just a feature not available on History Stack Exchange?

**Quick update**

below I've attached some screen shots from my machine. as you can see there are no comment buttons in the history stack exchange site (1st picture) but there are comment buttons on my Stack Overflow account.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you looking for this "button"? I just clicked a link that says "add comment" to display this message. You should see this link below each question and each answer. If you are looking for a comments button for the site in general, then I am not aware of one. In fact, I don't recall seeing one on other SE sites either, but I could be wrong.

Comment: added addendum and specifics

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of those questions where you need to read the [FAQ on Reputation](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)

Basically most SO sites want you to contribute, generally by answers, to build up your reputation.  Since Answers are what are wanted the expectation is that you will provide those, then comment later on once you have learned how things work.

Since you have 26 rep at the time of this writing, and leaving comments requires 50, you won't see the link.

Comment: i completely forgot about that. thanks!

Comment: Duh! I should have thought of that!